# How do I send POST NVP api request in VBA?

Tags: vba, nvp

```
Dim req As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
req.Open "POST", "https://somewebsite.com/vpc"
req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/plain"
req.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/xml"
req.send "Code=12345&Amount=100&Account=user......."
Debug.Print req.responseText
```

I get Account was+not+present+in+the+request in responseText

Updated questions:  What is the format or syntax where you can send POST NVP in VBA?

Comment: Without access to the docs for the API in question, how could we know what's the correct format?

Comment: are you able to successfully make the same request in postman or curl etc.?

Comment: Yes, the command worked in postman.  I want to how to do it in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Cyboashu, I looked at the header in postman, copy it and got it to worked in VBA.  Here is code in case anyone is wondering

```
Dim req As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
req.Open "POST", "https://somewebsite.com/vpc"
req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
req.send "Code=12345&Amount=100&Account=user......."
Debug.Print req.responseText
```